# Is it possible to add WAF to ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, amazon-waf

I've picked up a project that uses ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService, deployed via CDK, and I need to protect this with a WAF. Is it possible to add WAF to the load balancer or is the only way to put this behind CloudFront?

I think if I created the WebACL directly through the AWS Console I could then select object such as load balancers to apply it to, but not sure if that would include the ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the CDK can [associate](https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/security/200_labs/200_basic_ec2_with_waf_protection/3_create_alb_with_waf/) a WAF ACL with an ALB.

The CDK [AWS::WAFv2 Construct Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2-readme.html) exposes the [CfnWebACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnWebACL.html) to create the ACL and the [CfnWebACLAssociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnWebACLAssociation.html) to associate the WebACL with your ALB.  These are so-called [L1 constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html). They correspond 1:1 to CloudFormation equivalents.

You need to pass the ALB Arn to the association as the `resourceArn`.  You can get the Arn from your `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` construct, which has a property `loadBalancer.loadBalancerArn`.

```js
const cfnWebACLAssociation = new wafv2.CfnWebACLAssociation(this, 'MyCfnWebACLAssociation', {
  resourceArn: myAlbFargateService.loadBalancer.loadBalancerArn,
  webAclArn: myCfnWebAcl.attrArn,
});
```